# OVH VPS Postfix can't receive external emails

Tags: networking, server, email, postfix, vps

I hope this is the right place where to ask for this kind of stuff, If not, please let me know.

I'm pretty new to mail server in generals, I bought a VPS from OVH services for other needs and decided to give postfix a go, It's Ubuntu 20.10, I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-20-04), as im pretty sure many others did, and although everything goes well, and I can even send to one of the addresses I set-up, an email from s-nail (so from the server to postfix anddresses), plus correctly send them to any external address (tried gmail and yahoo, still with s-nail), I can't for whatever reason, receive any. I tried to send the server an email using yahoo client and I always get an error email in response

```
Sorry, we were unable to deliver your message to the following address. Relay access denied
```

Now, I don't know specifically *what* to look for or *where* to look for, but here are the things I know:

- I have a domain that's working correctly with Apache, and it's reachable, so technically reverse dns should be ok
- My firewall isn't blocking postfix
- I have checked the domain records, I have 2 MX records with different priorities

| Domain | TTL | Type | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mydomain.com | 0 | MX | mx#.mail.ovh.net. |
| mydomain.com | 0 | MX | mx#.mail.ovh.net. |

Where **#** is the number of the (probably) ovh mails domains, it was automatically setup after I got the domain and VPS, I haven't changed it.

If I do in my terminal

```
host mydomain.com
```

I get

```
mydomain.com has address myipaddress
mydomain.com mail is handled by 1 mx#.mail.ovh.net.
mydomain.com mail is handled by 10 mx#.mail.ovh.net.
```

So the MX record should be...correct? I don't know really.

If I do in my terminal

```
dig MX mydomain.com
```

I get

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com.   2929    IN      MX      10 mx#.mail.ovh.net.
mydomain.com.   2929    IN      MX      1 mx#.mail.ovh.net.
;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
```

What could be the problem here? I was thinking something to do with the reverse dns but if that was the case then my domain shouldn't be reachable, right? And it is. I really don't know what to look for here to solve this, I was hoping you guys could save me this headache.

Comment: Is this running on a Ubuntu machine?

Comment: @David yes, sorry I thought it was implied since it's askubuntu, my bad, Ubuntu 20.10